# Shell is adding single quotes to variables that rsync fails on

Tags: shell, rsync, quote

Shell (`/bin/bash`) is adding single quotes to variables read in from a file in a `for` loop and causing `rsync` to fail.

I have an shell script doing a bunch of `rsync`s. The input file looks like this:
`/home/account/this` subdirectory

The for loops looks like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for SOURCE_DEST in `cat file_list`
do
    rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' account@domain.com:$SOURCE_DEST
done
```

Without `IFS=$'\n'`, the default causes `$SOURCE_DEST` to only contain:
`/home/account/this` instead of `/home/account/this subdirectory`.

However, when I run this script with the `IFS=$'\n'`, it puts single quotes around the `$SOURCE_DEST` such as: `'account@domain.com:/home/account/this subdirectory'` which causes rsync to fail and do strange things.

Example:

```
rsync --delete-after -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' 'account@domain.com:/home/account/this subdirectory'
```

which fails, and what I need is this without the single quotes:

```
rsync --delete-after -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' account@domain.com:/home/account/this subdirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume none of the names contain spaces, since you're using a space as a delimiter, so how about something like this:

```
while read line
do
    line=($line) # split line on its spaces
    rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' account@domain.com:${line[0]} ${line[1]}
done < file_list
```

This reads your file_list a line at a time, splits it at the space, then uses the first and second "word" it had as the args.

As pointed out by Johnsyweb, you might have meant that the directory actually did have a space and you wanted to pass that to `rsync`. In  that case, I'd say:

```
while read line
do
    rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 2222' "account@domain.com:${line// /\ }"
done < file_list
```

That should cause all spaces to be escaped, which I think might be what you were missing before.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, `${SOURCE_DEST}` should be `/home/account/this subdirectory`, which contains a space.

Comment: Hm. you might be right -- I thought about that at first but wasn't sure how to make sense of it. If so, shouldn't be much harder. I'll update with solution for that too then.

Comment: Yes, there should be a space there because it's copying SOURCE path to a DEST path.

Comment: So, in other words, you want to copy from the remote host `/home/account/this` to a local directory `subdirectory`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry for the confusion, I thought I had treated it like "code" in the forum, but I'm still learning how to use this interface.

Comment: The first example by Fatal Error solved the problem!
So IFS=$'\n' does not have an effect when using 'read line' in a while loop?

Comment: Here using `read` reads a whole line without having to change IFS at all, so you can take any side effects of changing it out of the picture.